Problema: la paginación no se borra después de aplicar filtros
Tengo un problema con la paginación, que ocurre cuando vuelvo a aplicar filtros después de haber buscado en algunas páginas.
Nota: estoy utilizando un plugin de filtrado
Para simplificar, imagine este escenario:
Hay 2 atributos: "color" y "tamaño". Los posibles términos de "color" son "azul" y "rojo", mientras que los términos de "tamaño" son "M" y "S"
Hay 90 productos "azules", y de esos solo 20 tienen talla "M".
El número de productos por página se establece en 30.
Una vez en la página de la tienda, si aplico el color azul filtro, obtengo 3 páginas, cada una con 30 productos.
El URL es:
mystore.com/shop/?q=1&pa_color=blue
Si me muevo a la segunda página, obtengo esta URL:
mystore.com/shop/page/2?q=1&pa_color=red
Finalmente, después de aplicar el Talla M filtro, aparece un error de "página no encontrada". Esto sucede porque el complemento mantiene el filtro de paginación, mientras aplica el nuevo tamaño filtro, como sugiere la URL:
mystore.com/shop/page/2?q=1&pa_color=red&pa_size=M
El filtro de paginación debe borrarse cuando se apliquen nuevos filtros. ¿Cómo se puede arreglar esto? ¿Existe una configuración que habilita este comportamiento?
Tengo entendido que quiza podria ser porque falta una "/" al final del numero de pagina, pero no se como agregarla o configurarla.
Gracias de antemano.

Porque has duplicado la pregunta? Te la van a cerrar o borrar

"quiza podria ser porque falta una "/" al final del numero de pagina?" no, es mas probable que no haya 2 paginas de resultados para esos filtros .
Qué plugin de filtros estas usando? es posible que haya una versión con eso corregido: por lo general cuando creas un plugin de filtros o búsquedas es menester limpiar el fragmento de paginación ( ej: page/xxx ) o de taxonomías/categorías ( ej: shop/toys/ ); fragmentos que el resultado de los filtros genera y se usan para armar el url.
Un truco "barato" es meterle un input hidden con el numero de pagina al form que hace el filtrado, ya sea por php si el plugin provee un template editable o un hook (filter/action) al renderizar ó al mejor estilo slumprogramming™ vía javascript.
En un ejemplo práctico:

En el ejemplo un filtro que se arma con pequeños forms y buttons dentro de un dropdown de bootstrap ( la selección del "menú" hace el submit y wordpress se encarga del resto )
El html que genera el filtro, detalle en texto:
<div id="results-filters" class="wrap wide container">
  <div class="text-md-end text-center px-0 m-4">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-primary dropdown-toggle"
        type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
        aria-expanded="false">
        Sort By </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
          <form>
            <input type="hidden" name="orderby" value="name">
            <input type="hidden" name="order" value="ASC">
            <button class="dropdown-item btn btn-outline" type="submit">
              Name (A-Z) </button>
          </form>
        </li>
        <li>
          <form>
            <input type="hidden" name="orderby" value="name">
            <input type="hidden" name="order" value="DESC">
            <button class="dropdown-item btn btn-outline active" type="submit">
              Name (Z-A) </button>
          </form>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

El ejemplo tal vez se queda corto dado que ordenar los resultados ( el objetivo del filtro) no cambia la cantidad de los mismos, pero es una ocasión para "parchar" el comportamiento de que si estas en la última página y cambias el filtro te devuelve los resultados a partir de la última página.
Aquí el truco sería insertar el numero de página que queremos ( la primera ) dentro de cada mini form:
<input type="hidden" name="paged" value="1">

Sin acceso al php que genera el html, por javascript sería algo asi:
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

  jQuery('#results-filters form').each(function(){
    jQuery(this).append('<input type="hidden" name="paged" value="1" />');
  });

});

(*) siendo que es wordpress y presumo woocommerce, usamos jQuery por simplicidad, lo podes armar con vanilla javascript también.
(**) buscando entre los plugins que habitualmente uso con woocommerce no encontré ninguno con ese comportamiento, pero bueno no los conozco a todos, lo que sí te puedo comentar es que el theme storefront al armar sus filtros incluye el input hidden con el numero de pagina seteado a 1 :

Detalle en texto de filtro que setea el número de página a 1
<div class="storefront-sorting">
  <div class="woocommerce-notices-wrapper"></div>
  <form class="woocommerce-ordering" method="get">
    <select name="orderby" class="orderby" aria-label="Pedido de la tienda">
      <option value="menu_order">Orden predeterminado</option>
      <option value="popularity" selected="selected">Ordenar por popularidad</option>
      <option value="rating">Ordenar por puntuación media</option>
      <option value="date">Ordenar por los últimos</option>
      <option value="price">Ordenar por precio: bajo a alto</option>
      <option value="price-desc">Ordenar por precio: alto a bajo</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="paged" value="1">
  </form>
  <p class="woocommerce-result-count">
    Mostrando los 4 resultados</p>
</div>


